# How to find the CPU and Memory utilization for an android app in DDMS?

Tags: android, memory, cpu, ddms

How to find the CPU and Memory utilization for an android app in DDMS? I need a step by step assistance.

What is the difference between heap and allocated memory? Which actually is the real memory being used?

And I can see only a PI chart of CPU usage. How can I see the actual percentage of CPU usage?

Thanks in advance,
Terminator

Answer (score 0):

You can try third party tools, such as TaskSpy on Google Play.

It provides you with intuitive charts and enables you to profile one specific running app

[image]